# How to save/update array of posts in Wordpress at once?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating my own plugin and I have created an array called **$titles_arr**

and it looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>                  Acrobotics Wants To Kickstart Smarter Cities With Its Smart Citizen Environment Sensors         
    [1] =>                  Leaked Memo Shows Barnes & Noble Bringing Web Browser And Email To Simple Touch eReaders In June            
    [2] =>                  How Cheap Genetic Testing Complicates Cancer Screening For Us All           
    [3] =>                  Android’s Design Principles And The Calculus Of The Human Pleasure Response         
    [4] =>                  Iterations: How Tech Hedge Funds And Investment Banks Make Sense Of Apple’s Share Buybacks          
    [5] =>                  Yahoo Board Has Approved A $1.1 Billion Cash Deal For Tumblr, WSJ Reports
)
```

and I need to save this "titles" as posts. I mean, 6 posts will be created and each of them will have the one title from the array.

Other things like date, body, excerpt etc. could be default or null. I will change them later in admin if needed.

And I would like to set state to `draft` instead of published.

What is the best practice how to do such task? I am creating my own plugin and need some advice how to save multiple posts at once in wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```
global $user_ID; // logged in user id
$term = get_term_by('name', 'Php', 'category'); // Category name assumed 'Php'
$cat = $term->term_id; // get the id of Php category
$titles = array('Post-One', 'Post-Two'); // your titles array
foreach($titles as $title)
{
    $new_post = array(
        'post_title' => $title,
        'post_content' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
        'post_status' => 'draft',
        'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'post_author' => $userID,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_category' => array($cat)
    );
    wp_insert_post($new_post); // insert the post
    // Or
    $newPostId = wp_insert_post($new_post); //  the new post ID in $newPostId
}
```